# vertx get to external address

Tags: java, dns, httpclient, vert.x

Hi I'm trying to make a request to external service with the use of httpClient vert.x but I keep getting error: Search domain query failed. Original hostname: 'google.com' failed to resolve 'google.com'
What am i missing in the code below? I'm not sure about those AddressResolverOptions, I have read about them but still I'm not sure what they are responsible for. I'd like to make the request the simplest possible way but the more I investigate the more difficult it seems

```
package io.vertx.starter;

import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.core.VertxOptions;

import io.vertx.core.dns.AddressResolverOptions;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpClientOptions;
import io.vertx.ext.unit.Async;
import io.vertx.ext.unit.TestContext;
import io.vertx.ext.unit.junit.VertxUnitRunner;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Collections;

@RunWith(VertxUnitRunner.class)
public class MainVerticleTest {

  private Vertx vertx;

  @Before
  public void setUp(TestContext tc) {
     vertx = Vertx.vertx(new VertxOptions().setAddressResolverOptions(
       new AddressResolverOptions().addSearchDomain("google.com").addSearchDomain("bar.com"))
     );
//    vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    vertx.deployVerticle(MainVerticle.class.getName(), tc.asyncAssertSuccess());
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown(TestContext tc) {
    vertx.close(tc.asyncAssertSuccess());
  }

  @Test
  public void testThatTheServerIsStarted(TestContext tc) {

    final HttpClientOptions httpClientOptions = new HttpClientOptions();
    httpClientOptions.setConnectTimeout(300);
    httpClientOptions.setIdleTimeout(5);
//    httpClientOptions.` `
    httpClientOptions.setSsl(true).setTrustAll(true);
//    final URL url = new URL("currentUrl");

    Async async = tc.async();

    vertx.createHttpClient(httpClientOptions).getNow(
      443,"google.com", "/", response -> {
      System.out.println(response.statusCode());
      async.complete();
      });
//
//    Async async = tc.async();
//    vertx.createHttpClient().getNow(8080, "localhost", "/", response -> {
//      tc.assertEquals(response.statusCode(), 200);
//      response.bodyHandler(body -> {
//        tc.assertTrue(body.length() > 0);
//        async.complete();
//      });
//    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you try removing the search domains? A search domain is a domain that's appended to the end of the domain names you're asking for. So if you query for `example.com` and you have `google.com` as a search domain, it would lookup `example.com.google.com`.

Comment: Perhaps it's an issue with the async DNS resolver. Can you try again with the `-Dvertx.disableDnsResolver=true` sys prop?